# How can I read and print a file in eclipse with relative paths?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, relative-path

I'm trying to read a file in eclipse and print it. The problem is that the compiler always says to me that the file or directory doesn't exist. I have to use relative paths.

The relevant part of the project routes is:

- uva.pfc.refactoringEngine.core <--Project

  - ...
  - src

    - uva.pfc.refactoringengine.core.actions <-- Actual Package

      - ...
      - CreateEnumSetPlusClas.java <--File from I want to read the EnumSetPlus.java file
    - ...
    - EnumSetPlus.java <-- File I want read and print

This is the code:

```
String total="";

File actual = new File("src/EnumSetPlus.java"); 

FileReader filereader = null; 

try { 
filereader = new FileReader(actual); 
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
// TODO Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); 
} 

BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(filereader); 

try { 
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) 
{ 
total += line + "\n"; 
} 
input.close(); 
} 
catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); 
} 

System.out.println(total);
```

I think the problem is that I have to do something if I want the file path recognised by de eclipse project.

Could you help me??

Thaks beforehand.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/EnumSetPlus.txt")` - this will look for the file on the root of the classpath (which is `bin/`, but all files from src go to bin). You then get an `InputStream` which you can adapt to `Redaer` via `new InputStreamReader(stream, encoding)`

Comment: getResourceAsStream returns null and then throws and error :(

Comment: check if the file is indeed there (in bin)

Comment: the getResourceAsStream should work. Are you sure you didn't forget the forward slash?

Comment: sorry, You are right!, I seen the EnumSetPlus.class file in the bin directory before. I though it was the .java, but it was the .class.

Comment: I have copied the EnumSetPlus.java file into bin directory and... everything is ok!. Thanks!!!

Comment: One last thing, sorry because of my English level XD. I'm Spanish and maybe my writing is not the best it could!.

Comment: You should automate this - you should not rely on manual copying. Eclipse does not copy .java files, so perhaps you may want to rename this to .javax for example

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse the current working directory is `src` by default.

Try this

```
File actual = new File("EnumSetPlus.txt");
```

Also I would look into Kevin's answer too. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
String filePath = "/EnumSetPlus.java";
File actual = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(filePath).getFile());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example says that you want to read a file called **EnumSetPlus.java** but the source code is looking for a file called **EnumSetPlus.txt**.